# Nativescript Firebase Plugin storage functions on NS7 error

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-plugin, nativescript-firebase

After upgrading to NS7, and updating my code imports, I am unable to use the firebase 'firestore' functions. Whenever any firebase storage function is called I receive:
`CONSOLE ERROR: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'listAll' of undefined`

This same app is able to use successfully use firestore to retrieve collections and documents, but storage functions do not seem to be recognized.

app.component.ts

```
import { firestore, storage } from "@nativescript/firebase";

 storage.listAll({
        bucket: "gs://appname-xxxx.appspot.com",
        remoteFullPath: ""
      }).then(
          function (result) {
              console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
          },
          function (error) {
              console.log(error);
          }
      );
```

firebase.nativescript.json

```
{
    "using_ios": true,
    "using_android": false,
    "analytics": true,
    "firestore": true,
    "realtimedb": false,
    "authentication": true,
    "remote_config": false,
    "performance_monitoring": false,
    "external_push_client_only": false,
    "messaging": false,
    "in_app_messaging": false,
    "crashlytics": true,
    "storage": true,
    "functions": false,
    "facebook_auth": true,
    "google_auth": true,
    "admob": false,
    "dynamic_links": false,
    "ml_kit": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following import format

```
import { storage } from "@nativescript/firebase/storage";
```

This will avoid "undefined"